# How to get GeoJSON properties to appear in openlayers 3 popup when using CLUSTERS?

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers-3

I've built a relatively simple openlayers map and I'm attempting to get my geoJSON properties to appear in my on-click popup but no matter what I try, it either returns the geometry name `object Object` or `Undefined`. I think openlayers stores cluster data as an array of features rather than multiple individual features? Here is the code for my on-click function:

```
var
   container = document.getElementById('popup'),
   content_element = document.getElementById('popup-content'),
   closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

closer.onclick = function() {
overlay.setPosition(undefined);
closer.blur();
return false;
};

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
element: container,
positioning: 'bottom-center',
stopEvent: false
});

map.addOverlay(overlay);
// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
  function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
if (feature) {
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

    var content =coord;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    content += '<h5>' + feature.get('MMSI') + '</h5>';
//--------^^^^^^^ This does not work for clusters ^^^^^^------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    content_element.innerHTML = content;
    overlay.setPosition(coord);
} else {

}
```

I don't need the properties of the actual clusters but I do need the properties of a single point(once zoomed in and the clusters have separated into individual points). Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var ft = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(f, l){return f;});
    if (ft) {
        var features = ft.get('features'); //this is from the official examples
        features.forEach(function(feature){

            //assumption there is a 'name' property
            console.info(feature.get('name'));

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahaaa! Thank you so much! Been working on this problem for a while...seems kinda simple now...